# Где хранить текстовые файлы

Tags: apk, файлы

Учусь кодить под Андроид в Eclips. (до этого писал на Delphi)
Создаю приложение, которое должно работать с небольшими текстами в простом формате txt. Создавать, записывать, редактировать. Типа блокнота.
Создаю: ***private final static String FILENAME = "D:\readme.txt"***;
Потом использую: ***InputStream inputstream = openFileInput(FILENAME);***
Результат: программа не может найти этот файл. Скорее всего я не правильно указываю путь. 
**Вопросы:**
**1**.Как правильно указывается путь?
**2**.Можно ли указать какой-то универсальный каталог, для хранения файлов, НО такой, чтобы когда приложение будет установлено на внешнее ус-во (планшет), не вносить изменения в программу. В идеале на SD карте.
**3**.При создании файла apk, созданная папка с файлами txt автоматически упаковалась в пакет.

Comment: Так вы далеко не уедете. Начните [отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/texteditor.php), например.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, отличная ссылка. 

Прочитал и понял, что, наверное, я никогда не возьмусь за программирование на Android (только если с целью придумать что-то попроще, поближе к людям).

Comment: @avp, на самом деле, среда, будь то eclipse или android stodio, многое делает за программиста. это и создание интерфейса почти (поначалу по крайней мере) визуальное и автокомплит классов и методов. реально кода надо написать не так много. для обучения хватает пары дней. вот дальше и глубже изучать уже не так страшно, благо туториалов и прочих скринкастов по конкретным проблемам полно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, видимо, я недостаточно ясно сказал -- сама архитектура среды программирования (не разработки) слишком далека от KISS, поэтому порочна.

Comment: То, откуда вы рекомендуете начать, я и начал, но мне нужно явно указать путь к файлу, который находится на диске. Я об этом спрашивал.

Comment: Упрощу вопрос: как загрузить или сохранить файл с диска, например d:\ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала надо понять, какой файл и откуда вы хотите открыть.

Файлы бывают:

1. В ресурсах. Например, лежащие в res/raw. Открыть такой файл можно через `Resources.openRawResource()`. Будет что-то вроде `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);`. Сохранять такие файлы придется в другое место. То, что в пакете не модифицируется. N.B. указывается идентификатор ресурса, а не имя файла. Это, видимо, ответ на ваш пункт 3. Об этом варианте упомянуто в статье.
2. В директории приложения во внутренней памяти. Чтение `openFileInput(FILENAME,...)`, запись `openFileOutput(FILENAME,...)`. `FILENAME` - это не путь, а имя файла. Также в статье именно этот вариант разбирается.
3. В директории приложения во внешней памяти (встроенная память, sd-карта). Доступ к таким фалам делается так (сокращенный кусок кода):

   ```
   File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), FILENAME);
   //Для чтения
   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
   byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
   is.read(data);
   is.close();

   //Для записи
   OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
   os.write(data);
   os.close();
   ```

   Вероятно, именно про этот вариант вы спрашивали в пункте 2.
    4. Для директорий публичных папок пользуемся `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` вместо `getExternalFilesDir`.
    5. Для произвольных директорий можно идти от `getRootDirectory`.

Для директорий приложения (во внутренней памяти, во внешней) система при удалении приложения сама все почистит.

ЗЫ Для 4,5 пунктов требуются разрешения `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` в манифесте.
ЗЗЫ Для kitkat и далее есть новые функции для доступа к п.3, см. в доках.
ЗЗЗЫ На самом деле, в той статье достаточно самостоятельный пример, надо было его повторить и потом уже потрошить. Вы начали придумывать задачу на ходу, в итоге вопрос свелся к тому, что надо читать доки...

Comment: в том смысле, что "диска d:\" в андроид нет, а есть куча разных девайсов, начиная от телефонов и планшетов, заканчивая телевизорами и часами, и у всех у них разные хранилища, а у некоторых их и вовсе нет, или есть номинально или виртуально.

Comment: Благодарю за исчерпывающий ответ! Согласен, что надо читать доки, но хочется, блин, поскорее, а в результате, потерянное время. 
Еще раз благодарю!